# How to swap contents of two different HashMaps efficiently

Tags: rust

In C++ I can swap the contents of two HashMap's(`std::unordered_map`) using the `swap` method. How to achieve the same in Rust?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/swap

Comment: [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html)? This is commonly use (or more likely `std::mem::take` or `std::mem::replace`) to gain control of the contents of a collection without having ownership of the collection.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike C++, Rust does not need a specialized `swap()` for each type, because it has destructive moves swaps are always simple copies in memory.

You could write your own:

```rust
fn swap(a: &mut HashMap<String, String>, b: &mut HashMap<String, String>) {
    let temp = std::mem::take(a);
    *a = std::mem::take(b);
    *b = temp;
}
```

But the standard library already contains an even more optimized, and generic, implementation - [`std::mem::swap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.swap.html):

```rust
fn swap(a: &mut HashMap<String, String>, b: &mut HashMap<String, String>) {
    std::mem::swap(a, b);
}
```